# How to access display device from docker

Tags: docker, framebuffer

I have a frame buffer sample code(square.c) to draw a square on screen.It was successfully executed on my Virtual Machine.Now i have to run this c application inside a Ubuntu container.But when i run this application from the container it shows a message as Error: cannot open framebuffer device: No such file or directory.
Reason for the error:Cannot open /dev/fb0.(fb0 is not present).I would like to know is there any method to access display device from docker.

I have successfully compiled and executed sqaure.c(Framebuffer code) in Virtual Machine.Now i tried to run the same code inside the ubuntu container which is actually running inside my virtual Machine.

docker file

## Download base image ubuntu

FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER xxaxaxax

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim

RUN apt-get -y install gcc

RUN mkdir /home/test

ADD hello /home/test
ADD square /home/test    -->sqare->executable of square.c

Comment: As a general rule you can’t access the host’s hardware devices from Docker containers, and if accessing the host’s hardware devices is a core part of your application you might reconsider why you want to use Docker with it.  Especially if you’re dealing with direct framebuffer access, I’d stick with the working VM solution you already have (because that _can_ virtualize the display, unlike Docker).

Comment: Thanks for the the support David,your comment is clear.So docker does not support any apllication which uses host's hardware device,right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you CAN use host's hardware in docker.
use --privileged to gain access to all devices (like in /dev/)
or use --device=/dev/fb0 option when running the container. note that if you add a device to the machine the device will not be seen in a running container.

Comment: Hi! Something to keep in mind when posting an answer is to look at when the question was first asked.  In this case the question is over 2 years old.  The question is ambiguous.  Is the OP asking about the GPU or actually using the display from the container.  The later could not be done 2 years ago.  I've been told, as of this writing, that the later still cannot be done.

Comment: Hi! One thing to keep in mind when answering a question like this is the age of the question.  Docker has change a lot in the last two years.  I would encourage you to qualify your answer with some references to a version of docker.  In addition  I have found that meaningful answers to old questions like this also have some acknowledgement as to what may have been able to be done around the time when the question was posted. 

Thank you for answering the question!  Please keep contributing :D